# sort object base on array to produce sorted array

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

Object doesn't guantee order when I display it so I have to convert an existing object into array, but follow the order.

I have this array as the order `[1,2,3]`

and this is my raw input aka source

```
{'2': 'two',
'3': 'three',
'1':'one'}
```

How can I make a function to produce a new array where the order follow the sorted key above?

I'm stuck at this stage

```
//expected 
['one', 'two', 'three']
const order = ['1', '2', '3']
const source = {
  '2': 'two',
  '3': 'three',
  '1': 'one'
}

let sorted = Object.keys(source).map(o => {
  //return order.includes(o) ? //what to do here : null
})
```

I think I have to do loop within loop.

Comment: I find it funny how you post a problem that should in all normal cases not be solved by using property order, realize that, and then use about the only example possible where relying on property order would work.

Answer (score 3):

Can simply map `order` array and return the corresponding value from `source`. Anything beyond that is over complicating it

```js
const order = ['1', '2', '3']
const source = {
  '2': 'two',
  '3': 'three',
  '1': 'one'
}

const sorted = order.map(n=>source[n])

console.log(sorted)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce the ordering array, and find the relevant strings from the source object. This method uses only one loop, and thus, is more efficient.

```js
const order = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'];
const source = {
  '2': 'two',
  '5': 'five',
  '3': 'three',
  '1': 'one',
  '4': 'four'
};

let sorted = order.reduce((obj, item) => {
  obj.push(source[item]);
  return obj;
}, []);

console.log(sorted);
```